# Does the local weather affect the pokemon types that appear?

Tags: pokemon-go

Do the area determine the probability of the pokemon types? For example; if I live on a very hot area, or near the sea, or in a windy mountain, or a very cold place.

Or maybe the pokemons are just completely random?

Comment: I've noticed a lot more water pokemon in my area since it started raining. I am also far enough from any body of water to normally see water pokemon

Comment: I find it unlikely that Niantic would devote the amount of storage and CPU needed to analyze live weather on their central servers. If the local app is downloading weather data, that should be easy to detect with WiFi packet sniffing.

Answer (score 9):

The location is very important:

> ... what Pokémon you can encounter depends largely on your location. Walk near a beach, and you’ll find more Water types, for example.

(from [here](http://daily.pokecommunity.com/2016/07/06/a-guide-to-pokemon-go/))

I cannot find anything that relates weather to the Pokemon types. I don't think it is an influence factor.

Comment: for example: haven't encountered any water pokemon around except a magikarp when i was walking near a pond

Comment: Yep. I really, really love this kind of interaction with the environment. Getting only Pidgeys and Ratatas while working (in a grassy environment), and hopefully will get some others while walking near water or buildings

Answer (score 8):

**I am personally confident that weather plays a part in spawning Pokemon, through personal experience.**

To quote [the official FAQ](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221957648-Finding-and-Catching-wild-Pok%C3%A9mon);

> Some wild Pokémon appear only in certain environments **and climates**. For example, some Pokémon may appear only near lakes, oceans, or other bodies of water.

At first, I did not read much into it. However, we have had some considerable rainfall during the last two days, and there was a noticeable difference. Instead of my street being filled with Doduo, I was finding Polywhirl and Staryu. In contrast, not a single water Pokemon has appeared in the previous few days leading from the release. This includes in a small area, nearby, that is misrepresented as a small lake.

Ultimately, it is not difficult to gather weather statistics, from a development point of view. Especially on a phone, which already has such information 'localised' for weather applications.

Comment: Just a correction:  Climate != weather, it's the general weather over a long period of time (i.e. it rainy, hot, and muggy in Florida during the summer, it snows in the Northern US in the winter, etc.).
But based on anecdotal evidence I've seen from others and from myself last night driving around during a storm, it does appear there may be a correlation between current weather and pokemon types

Comment: As someone who lives in a city full of Doduos and with constant rain, I can tell this is not the case. Rain or no rain, Doduos are the most common pokemon around.

Answer (score 3):

> Do the area determine the probability of the pokemon types?

This is what the Pokémon Go description says on the Google Play store:

> **Certain Pokémon appear near their native environment**—look for Water-type Pokémon by lakes and oceans.

I live in a [big city](https://www.google.com.mx/maps/place/Guadalajara,+Jalisco/@20.6737778,-103.4054539,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8428b18cb52fd39b:0xd63d9302bf865750!8m2!3d20.6596988!4d-103.3496092?hl=en), with no real rivers, lakes or big water sources.

I have found many water pokémon and I haven't been around a water source at all. Not even fountains. So far I have caught Krabby, Kingler, Goldeen, Staryu, Horsea and Squirtle (besides the starter one).

So maybe *some* pokémon will require you to move to a lake, or a river, or a volcano, but not all of them.

I'm still not sure on how much effect the location has on the game and the pokémon you find, but the game just launched 2 days ago in NZ and Japan. Maybe the pokémon we (players outside those countries) find will be more location accurate once the game is officially released globally.

Comment: Maybe it just affects probability, as I was saying in the question

Comment: Maybe, and then, maybe not. A third of the pokémon I've caught are water types, another third normal types, and then some grass and bugs. It's not very conclusive to me. And if Niantic has taught us something with Ingress, is that they are not very open with how their software works.