# Do certain Pokemon types appear more often in some locations?

Tags: pokemon-go

Various reports claim that Pokemon are more likely to be found in their appropriate environments, such as water types near water. Is this true, or is it just observation bias with pseudo-random placement?

If true, what are the preferred places to find each type?

(Bug, Dark, Dragon, Electric, Fairy, Fighting, Fire, Flying, Ghost, Grass, Ground, Ice, Normal, Poison, Psychic, Rock, Steel, Water)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Pokemon always appear in the same spot?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273233/do-pokemon-always-appear-in-the-same-spot)

Comment: The title is different, but the accepted answer also points out that location affects types found.

Comment: @NBN-Alex, once again, answers do not count towards making a question a duplicate. If they are two differant questions, and one just happens to have an answer that addresses the other, they are not duplicate **questions**.

Comment: @Timelord64 - I happened to be on the second question before seeing this one, which is why the duplicate flag seemed the best choice.

Comment: Answers don't belong in the question.  Please don't use it as such.  If you want to compile a list of where they show up, you can write your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pokemon spawns are very much affected by location.

The real world is split up into [a number of biomes](https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884#file-pokemon-go-data-dump-txt-L509). Spawn chances, rates, and available Pokemon are very much biome dependent. This data is likely pulled from Google Maps and Ingress, with some minor alterations.

For example, it is far more likely for a Muk to spawn in an Urban environment than it is for it to spawn in a Meadow.

### Biome List

- BASIN
- CANAL
- CEMETERY
- CINEMA
- COLLEGE
- COMMERCIAL
- COMMON
- DITCH
- DOCK
- DRAIN
- FARM
- FARMLAND
- FARMYARD
- FOOTWAY
- FOREST
- GARDEN
- GLACIER
- GOLF_COURSE
- GRASS
- HIGHWAY
- HOSPITAL
- HOTEL
- INDUSTRIAL
- LAKE
- LAND
- LIBRARY
- MAJOR_ROAD
- MEADOW
- MINOR_ROAD
- NATURE_RESERVE
- OCEAN
- PARK
- PARKING
- PATH
- PEDESTRIAN
- PITCH
- PLACE_OF_WORSHIP
- PLAYA
- PLAYGROUND
- QUARRY
- RAILWAY
- RECREATION_AREA
- RESERVOIR
- RESIDENTIAL
- RETAIL
- RIVER
- RIVERBANK
- RUNWAY
- SCHOOL
- SPORTS_CENTER
- STADIUM
- STREAM
- TAXIWAY
- THEATRE
- UNIVERSITY
- URBAN_AREA
- WETLAND
- WOOD
- DEBUG_TILE_OUTLINE
- DEBUG_TILE_SURFACE
- OTHER

Comment: That data dump is VERY interesting, thaks for posting it! Where was it obtained? Do we know if those biomes are all actually used right now?

Comment: @youR.Fate I dumped this data myself. You can replicate this dump by extracting the APK and pulling the strings out of some resources file.

Comment: Awesome pipe dream: if DEBUG_TILE_OUTLINE biome allows you to find a MISSINGNO.

Comment: Awesome dump. It would be interesting to cross-check that with user data like https://www.pokecrew.com/

Comment: Do you maybe want to update your link? This one currently only offers a re-direct.

Comment: @Ben I'll take care of that once I get home.

Answer (score 6):

It's true to an extent. Walk by river, you'll see lots more magikarp and psyducks, forests seem to contain grass type/normal type/and pikachu's, towns are generally bug type/normal type/flying type. Rock types are pretty random, haven't really found a good spot to farm them yet, same for electric and fire. They are seen pretty randomly. I don't know about ghosts being near graveyards, but I know you'll find them at night randomly as well.

Comment: The only ghastly I've seen hatched from an egg. And I've spent the past 3 nights playing until ~2 am. I'm going to assume there's more to it than just having it be night time.

Comment: @Ellesedil And they're not tied to night time, the only wild ghastly I've seen was just a little bit after noon in a downtown area

Comment: @SnoringFrog http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/274542/68492

Comment: @Ellesedil wow, up here in Canada I see Gastly all the time (more during the night than in the day) and Haunters occasionally. I've caught a Gengar too  but we used Pokevision to find it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to this link, there is an article that explains where you can find the different types of Pokemon: 
https://www.vg247.com/2016/08/25/pokemon-go-where-to-find-pokemon-types/

Just in case you can't access it, for some reason, here's the list:

Normal - More or less everywhere - that's why they're called Normal

Fire - Residential areas and neighbourhoods, warmer areas like beaches

Water - Rivers, streams, lakes, harbours, beaches - anywhere where there's water

Grass - Farms, forests, and parks are good options, as are gardens and golf courses

Bug - Farmland, woods and forests, gardens and generally grassy areas like parks, nature reserves, smaller pathways, golf courses and playgrounds.

Rock - Quarries, towns, parking buildings, train stations, highways, or large buildings such as shopping malls

Ground - Ditches, streams, parking garages, playgrounds, railway stations, roads and generally urban areas.

Electric -  Industrial parks, schools and college campuses, and other dry places that are largely concreted over

Fighting - Sports centres and stadiums, and they’ll also congregate around larger gyms.

Poison - Ponds, marshes, lakes, more industrial areas of cities and in large buildings

Fairy - Places of interest (local landmarks), churches or the cemetery.

Flying - Farmland, forests, woods and grassy areas such as nature reserves, playgrounds, parks and gardens.

Dragon - Famous places or landmarks

Ghost - Occasionally around churches, but they’ve also been reported to show up in built-up residential areas such as parking lots at night.

Ice - Grassy areas occasionally and near bodies of water more often than that. You’ll of course also find them anywhere there’s actual snow and ice.

Psychic - Grassy areas, but that’s pretty uncommon in general. Some also show up in residential areas but seemingly only at night. A better place to more reliably find them is in and around hospitals.

Steel - Inside or around larger building structures. They can also be found near railway stations and tracks.

Dark - In cinemas and theatres.

Comment: However, that article was written back in August, 2016.  Comments on that article portray it as reasonable but unsubstantiated speculation.

Comment: @Jerry Yes, but most of them are true. I've tried them and they work.

Comment: But how do you explain the experiences of others who claim those descriptions do not hold up?  How do you know your experience is not due to coincidence?