# Details of incense and how to make the most of it

Tags: pokemon-go

What is the best way to make use of an incense? I'm wondering about these details:

- Do they lure actual pokemon in your vicinity to your location, as in do they move from where they are at toward you?
- Can other people make use of your incense?
- Does the area you are at affect the type of pokemon that are drawn to you? For example, if I'm in a Dratini nest or near water where there's lots of water pokemon, can I expect the incense to pull a lot of them to me?
- Is it best to stay put or walk around when the incense is active?

Any other tips on how to make the best use of this?

Comment: Ah I didn't see that question pull up, thanks. It does answer half of my questions lol.

Comment: I know the question is answered, but he wasn't sure about bullet point #3. If anyone has more info on that, please share and I'll be sure to vote up.

Comment: see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273939/do-certain-pokemon-types-appear-more-often-in-some-locations/ somewhat related

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a link to a [comprehensive guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4tgrqw/hi_i_just_hit_level_25_and_wrote_a_comprehensive/) about Pokemon Go. He talks about Incense near the bottom of his post, I will copy it in here for clarity.

### How does moving affect how often Incense spawns Pokemon?

According to some game data files:

- StandingTimeBetweenEncountersSec: 300
- MovingTimeBetweenEncounterSec: 60
- DistanceRequiredForShorterIntervalMeters: 200

This means, in order to maximize the rate at which Incense spawns Pokemon, you need to walk 200 meters a minute. That’s a lot, and you’d basically need to be moving 7.5 mph (most people jog at 4-5 mph) do that. So if you’re at a brisk pace of ~3 miles per hour, you’re still getting spawns every 2 minutes or so, as opposed to every 300 seconds (5 minutes) while standing still.

**Basically, what he is saying is that to optimize the usage of your incense you should be at least walking or to get the most out of it you should either jog or run.**

---

### Other questions answered:

**Q:** Do they lure actual pokemon in your vicinity to your location, as in do they move from where they are at toward you?

**A:** No, Pokemon around you will not move to your location, your incense will spawn new Pokemon for you.

**Q:** Can other people make use of your incense?

**A:** No, others will not see Pokemon spawned by your incense. You can tell which Pokemon were spawned by your incense if you look at them on your map. The Pokemon will have a pink mist circling around them.

**Q:** Does the area you are at affect the type of pokemon that are drawn to you?

**A:** I am not too sure about this, maybe someone could help out with this question. From my experience, I have been getting Drowzees, Bellsprouts, Pidgey and Jynx which are all common to my area.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great info. I am definitely curious about the area affecting pokemon type, as I know of a place that has dratini and I want to use my incenses there to get more than my usual run. If anyone knows more about that, I'll vote them up for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Incense do not move the location to you, just spawn new pokemon (even with more rarity) next to you. 
The best is to walk while the incense is active so you get the incense pokemon and also the normal one you get by walking.

But the best use i did was activate incense, xp egg and lure module in two pokestops (close to each other)

Answer (score -1):

Incense essentially draws pokemon towards your location, it's often better to do this is more populated areas such as shopping malls or town centres, you'll get much better results than being in a forest or countryside. As mentioned by Sync you should probably be moving aswell, although I don't think you need to be moving at 7.5mph, just atleast walking in order to maximise the area in which the incense can be working in.

TL;dr
Use it in populated areas and try to atleast walk to make the most out of your incense.