# What groups of areas are there influencing the pokemons appearing?

Tags: pokemon-go

I just noticed when I'm at work close to water, I almost only encounter pokemons like magicarp, bublesaur or dragonite (Sorry for the names, I never played pokemon in english so I'm not that sure abotu the names beeing written properly).

And at home just normal and poison type mosnters. So I'm assuming the areas are grouped and connected to that the pokemons that appear are.

Is it known what areas exist and what pokemons are supposed to spawn in them?

If so, could someone provide a table/list?

Comment: Maybe the appearance of poison-pokemon in your home is a hint that you might want to work on your housekeeping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the local weather affect the pokemon types that appear?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272736/does-the-local-weather-affect-the-pokemon-types-that-appear)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I don't think that the linked question is a duplicate, because this question specifically asks for a list and not about whether or not there are biomes at all.

Comment: @Philipp The linked question does answer questions about the importance of location for Pokemon spawns, so I figured perhaps it was a dupe.

Comment: I definitely remember a question asking about areas and biomes, but I can't seem to find it now.

Answer (score 2):

There are in fact biomes in the game:

- Basin
- Canal
- Cemetery
- Cinema
- College
- Commercial
- Common
- Ditch
- Dock
- Drain
- Farm
- Farmland
- Farmyard
- Footway
- Forest
- Garden
- Glacier
- Golf Course
- Grass
- Highway
- Hospital
- Hotel
- Industrial
- Lake
- Land
- Library
- Major Road
- Meadow
- Minor Road
- Nature Reserve
- Ocean
- Park
- Parking
- Path
- Pedestrian
- Pitch
- Place Of Worship
- Playa
- Playground
- Quarry
- Railway
- Recreation Area
- Reservoir
- Residential
- Retail
- River
- Riverbank
- Runway
- School
- Sports Center
- Stadium
- Stream
- Taxiway
- Theatre
- University
- Urban Area
- Wetland
- Wood
- DEBUG_TILE_OUTLINE
- DEBUG_TILE_SURFACE
- Other

Data was sourced from an [APK dump](http://pastebin.com/saeAy5LZ) done by me, which can be independently verified by pulling strings from specific APK files.

However, this likely is not a full list of biomes available in-game. Some biomes (like desert, for example) would be server-side, and therefore not be listed in the game's biome resources.

Comment: Is there a way to figgure out which biomes are connected to which pokemons?

Comment: I hope the "Highway" biome is only to supress spawning of pokemon 0o

Comment: @Zaibis I've (as of yet) been unable to find that information. I know projects like The Silph Road and others are trying to essentially brute-force that information, but there is no authoritative link of data yet.

Comment: @Zaibis Yes. Quite a few of these (Highway, Runway, Taxiway, Quarry, etc) are most likely meant as no-spawn zones. Additionally, they can have distinctions on the in-game map.